# How to calculate the output of a regression decision tree

Tags: regression, random-forest, decision-tree, non-linear-regression, estimation

I'm trying to understand after doing all possible splits in a regression tree. you end up with terminal node(s) then you need to calculate the output to obtain the regression estimate. In this case what is the rule, is it to average the observations in the terminal node or use some weighted average if there are multiple terminal nodes?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. You simply just take the average of the values in the node. And why does that makes sense?

A decision tree actually divides your data into square-(hyper) boxes. Say your box (node) have the following values `[2,3,4]` from our training set, then when we get a new data point, we traverse the tree and end in that box, which value should we assign to the new data? Well, on average, we get the smallest error if we assign the average of the values `[2,3,4]` i.e `3` to the new data.